# How to create the list of all possible values from another list

Tags: python

With four letters in a list

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I would like to create another list with every letter in a combination so the result would look like:

```
['a-b', 'a-c', 'a-d'
'b-a', 'b-c', 'b-d',
'c-a', 'c-b', 'c-d',
'd-a', 'd-b', 'd-c']
```

How can it be done?

Comment: Have you looked at `itertools.permutations`?

Comment: Please post it as an answer so we could up vote it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate all permutations of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `itertools.permutations` function does exactly that

```py
from itertools import permutations

letters = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

print(["-".join(perm) for perm in permutations(letters, 2)])
```

If you don't care about ordering (so `a-b` would be the same as `b-a`) then use `itertools.combinations`

Answer (score 2):

Look into `permutations` :

```
import itertools 

permutations = list(itertools.permutations(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2))
permutations = [elem[0]+"-"+elem[1] for elem in permutations]
```

This achieves the same as the following, which you may be more familiar with :

```
permutations = []
for letter_1 in letters:
    for letter_2 in letters:
        if letter_1 != letter_2:
            permutations.append(letter_1 + "-" + letter_2)
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, there's a standard library function to generate all given-length permutations from a list:

```py
import itertools
combo = [ '-'.join(pair) for pair in itertools.permutations(letters,2) ]
```

For pairs from short lists, the basic list comprehension option is not too bad (but still second-best):

```py
combo = [ f+'-'+s for fx,f in enumerate(letters) for sx, s in enumerate(letters) if fx!=sx ]
```

Answer (score 2):

The you're looking to make all combinations of the elements of an array as suggested by @quamrana this can be done via `itertools.permutation`

This function takes the list and the length of the permutation as an
input and returns a iterator.

So you need to call

```
perms = itertools.permutations(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 2)
```

to get the iterator

Now you can iterate over it and add dashes in the middle via

```
result = [i[0]+"-"+i[1] for i in perms]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking to use the `itertools.permutations()` function:

```py
>>> import itertools
>>> res = [f"{i[0]}-{i[1]}" for i in itertools.permutations(letters, 2)]
>>> res
['a-b', 'a-c', 'a-d', 'b-a', 'b-c', 'b-d', 'c-a', 'c-b', 'c-d', 'd-a', 'd-b', 'd-c']
```